# Clearing cache after change the html code

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, caching, refresh

I've got some problem with clearing cache on web browsers. When I'm loading the changed website, even after deleting the cache, it does not load properly(on android browser - chrome, on pc it's all ok).

What can I do more except of deleting the cache, because I already did it? I need to add some code?

Edit: and what can I do for properly loading on iPhone(safari)?

Answer (score 0):

Clear data of the chrome then it will work fine . Even i had the same problem